# BigQuery: unexpected result after filtering table

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Given the following query (very simplified):

```
SELECT hits.page.pagepath AS Page
FROM
    `[projectid].[datasetid].ga_sessions_*` t, t.hits as hits
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190123' AND '20190123' 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM t.hits WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagepath,r'dames'))
```

I expected that this query only returns pages which contain 'dames', but this is actually not the case. With this filter in the WHERE section..

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM t.hits WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagepath,r'dames'))
```

..there is flattened on hit-level and filtered on only pages of dames. In the main query there is also flattened on hit-level. So I would expect that per hit there would be TRUE's and FALSE's where only TRUE's remain in the final dataset, namely only pages that contain 'dames'.

I know queries that do return the expected output, but my main question (purely to understand why this query is not working) is actually more: why does this query not work as expected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must understand, that cross-joining an unnested array with its parent row does not exactly flatten the source table. It repeats the parent row for every row in the array: in this case every session information gets repeated for every hit: the hits-array itself too!

That means for every hit you could lookup stuff in the whole session, because for every hit there are all hits available, because they too got repeated.

You are accessing this repeated hits array in your `WHERE` clause.

Instead of writing a sub-select on this repeated array, you want to use the newly available cross-joined fields from that array, i.e. `AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagepath,r'dames')`

It might be a bit confusing in your case, because your alias for the flattened hits is hits as well - you might want to consider renaming it to something different like `h` so your NOT working query looks like this

```sql
SELECT h.page.pagepath AS Page
FROM
    `[projectid].[datasetid].ga_sessions_*` t, t.hits as h
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190123' AND '20190123' 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM t.hits h2 WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath,r'dames'))
```

*You are checking for every page whether the whole session contained a page fulfilling your condition.*

The WORKING example would be

```sql
SELECT h.page.pagepath AS Page
FROM
    `[projectid].[datasetid].ga_sessions_*` t, t.hits as h
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190123' AND '20190123' 
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath,r'dames')
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this clarifies for a part. I knew about your last query, but was just curious why the first one doesn't work. However, what I still don't really get, is: what do you mean exactly with the fact that the hits array also repeats itself for every hit when I make the cross-join? Could you visualize it somehow with e.g. an example table? And I thought that when the parent row becomes available for every (hit) row, the table would be flattened, but as I read that's not exactly the case.

Comment: Flatten is a `CROSS JOIN` between an array and its parent. The parent gets repeated. The array is part of the parent. Therefore the array gets repeated - it doesn't disappear. UNNEST() creates a copy on the fly if you will. Try 
```WITH test AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    [
      STRUCT('a' as id, [12,23] as arr),
      ('b', [45,76])
    ]
  )
)

--SELECT * FROM test
SELECT * FROM test, test.arr as flat_arr```
And uncomment/comment the two queries ... Have a look at the JSON representation as well